# Making my own class.. how do i add type suggestions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

For example, if you make  UIButton it'll go 'buttonwithType:' and then give you a list of options as you type.

How do i add to that list with my own types for a separate object, and how do i make it know if it's a valid type for my object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIButtonType` is a `typedef`ed `enum`:

```
typedef enum {
   UIButtonTypeCustom = 0,
   UIButtonTypeRoundedRect,
   UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure,
   UIButtonTypeInfoLight,
   UIButtonTypeInfoDark,
   UIButtonTypeContactAdd,
} UIButtonType;
```

Creating a similar enum for some property of your class should clue Xcode in just fine; assuming the appropriate header is imported.